# Chef Manager persistence

Tags: chef-infra

My understanding is it is my personal responsibility to edit my local chef-repo and keep my workstation in sync with the version control system. Every time I use knife, my relevant workstation copies are transmitted to chef-server on the fly. Chef server would have no knowledge of the VCS. If all this is true, then when using the Chef Manager (chef-server-webui), how are Saves to edits of things like Data Bags persisted? Is it only in memory? If I make lots of edits in the webui (like say add 10 roles), how can I later make sure those changes are committed to the VCS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 possible workflows with data bags, roles, run lists and other such objects (if there are).

1. In the first one main server is Chef-Server. You create, edit and delete these on Chef-Server using your browser and chef-server-webui and then save the changes into your VCS using knife: 
   `knife data bag show -Fj ... > my_file.json`
2. Or vice versa, main server is VCS. You create and edit the objects using json files on your workstation and add them straight into VCS. And then upload and overwrite anything on Chef-Server with knife:
   `knife data bag from file ... my_file.json`

Use **one of those, but not both**! I personally use the 2nd workflow.

Answer (score 1):

They are persisted on the server, but there's a disparity between the Chef Server and the VCS server. Those objects are stored on the Chef Server when you use knife or the webui. They are committed to VCS when you use the CLI tool for your VCS (like `git` or `svn`). You are pushing different artifacts to different servers.